# Opening multiple files using command line arguments

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, command-line, command-line-arguments

Im having trouble opening bringing the text from multiple text files into a list. The texts to be brought in are represented by arguments following the program display so I need to use `sys.argv[1:]` however I hit an error:

```
  File "testa.py", line 19, in organize_data
    with open(sys.argv[1:],'r') as f:
TypeError: invalid file: ['test.txt', 'test2.txt']
```

changing `sys.argv[1:]` to `sys.argv[1]` runs properly but with just one text file. Im not sure how to properly bring 2 or more text files together into one list.

```
import sys
sys.argv
for argument in sys.argv:

    print("argument = " , argument)

print ("sys.argv = ", sys.argv)

print("first list item = " , sys.argv[ 0 ])

print("second list item = " , sys.argv[ 1 ])

files_used = sys.argv[1:]

def organize_data():
    word_list =[]
    bad_chars = ''',./<>?;:'"[{]}\|!@#$%^&*()_+-='''
    with open(files_used,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                word = word.strip(bad_chars)
                if word:
                    try:
                        _ = float(word)
                    except ValueError:
                        word_list.append(word.lower())
    return print(word_list)

organize_data()
```

Comment: `open` can only do one at a time; **iterate over them**.

Comment: you could do like `for fil in sys.argv[1:]: with open(fil,'r') as f:`

Comment: @jonrsharpe how would I do that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @AvinashRaj wouldnt that give me a syntax error?

Comment: @ShahobMousavi why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: with statement must be inside for loop. Don't put both on the same line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes of course, my apologies that works although the first text file does not seem to be included as part of the list